# 'DJI.WindowsSDK.DJISDKManager' threw an exception

Tags: dji-sdk

I recently downloaded the most recent DJI Windows SDK (2.0) in hopes to update my DLLs and be able to move forward with the new SDK. I can build the project but when I try to execute my app, it errors with the following:

```
'DJI.WindowsSDK.DJISDKManager' threw an exception. - Inner Exception.
FileNotFoundException: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

I've re-pulled the repo, using both Visual Studio 2017 and the 2019 Preview, I then tried the sample SDK and got the same error. I'm currently on Windows Build 17763.292. Is there something I'm missing? Anyone else with similar issues?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check is your references; here's mine from a working project:
[Solution References](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTle0.jpg)

Note my project uses JSON, so you may ignore the Newtonsoft NUGET. Also note the DJIWindowsWrapper reference is to the winmd file. Your project will probably build fine without this reference (mine does), but won't run.